# Unmet dependencies for fuerte-desktop-full on 12.04

Tags: ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just created a brand-new VM running 12.04 and am attempting to install ROS fuerte. I've followed the instructions from http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu to set up sources.list and keys and done `sudo apt-get update`. Running `sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full` fails with the following error:

`The following packages have unmet dependencies: ros-fuerte-desktop-full : Depends: ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo (= 1.6.15-s1346825464~precise) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Likewise, trying to install `ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo` gives:

`The following packages have unmet dependencies: ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo : Depends: ros-fuerte-bullet (= 2.79-s1346186848~precise) but it is not going to be installed Depends: ros-fuerte-common-msgs (= 1.8.13-0precise-20120813-1503-+0000) but it is not going to be installed Depends: ros-fuerte-common-rosdeps (= 1.2.0-s1346186808~precise) but it is not going to be installed Depends: ros-fuerte-driver-common (= 1.4.0-s1346186749~precise) but it is not going to be installed Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry (= 1.8.2-s1346187100~precise) but it is not going to be installed Depends: ros-fuerte-image-common (= 1.8.0-s1346187257~precise) but it is not going to be installed Depends: ros-fuerte-nodelet-core (= 1.6.5-s1346187746~precise) but it is not going to be installed Depends: ros-fuerte-perception-pcl (= 1.2.3-s1346187964~precise) but it is not going to be installed Depends: ros-fuerte-robot-model (= 1.8.1-s1346188771~precise) but it is not going to be installed Depends: ros-fuerte-ros (= 1.8.10-0precise-20120813-1418-+0000) but it is not going to be installed Depends: ros-fuerte-ros-comm (= 1.8.15-0precise-20120813-1503-+0000) but it is not going to be installed Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization-common (= 1.8.4-s1346192005~precise) but it is not going to be installed Depends: ros-fuerte-xacro (= 1.6.1-s1346189334~precise) but it is not going to be installed Depends: ros-fuerte-protobuf (= 0.1.0-s1346200515~precise) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

I've seen many, many other users with similar issues here, but none of the fixes I've found so far worked for me. I've tried to install `libboost1.46`, suggested [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/43187/cannot-install-at-all-ubuntu-1204-amd64/) but to no avail.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Robin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43369/unmet-dependencies-for-fuerte-desktop-full-on-12.04/) by [rdeits](https://answers.ros.org/users/3164/rdeits/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-09-07

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-09-07**:
simulator_gazebo 1.6.16 is out, so maybe you need to do sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get dist-upgrade first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is due to a [bug in the build](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5553) (already fixed, packages are being rebuilt right now).

For anyone reading this, I suggest waiting a little bit for the rebuild before trying the nuclear option. :)

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-09-21**:
According to that ticket, this is fixed.. but I'm still seeing this problem.. I've tracked it down to "The following packages have unmet dependencies: ros-groovy-visualization-common : Depends: nvidia-cg-toolkit but it is not installable".... and no, I don't have an nvidia card.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-10-03**:
Same problem, but ended up with a different solution.. http://answers.ros.org/question/44388/has-anyone-been-able-to-install-furte-on-an-x86_64-platform/